# Sync DB between Windows Mobile and MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, windows-mobile, synchronization

I am trying to create a windows mobile application that contains a database and can occasionally be connected to the Internet. When connected, I would like to sync the local database with the central database server. The central server is a MySQL server. The local database can be anything (probably SQL Compact).

What I did so far:

- Installed [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx)
- Installed [MySQL for ADO.NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html)
- Created a Smart Device Project
- Created a WCF Library (from [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004.aspx))
- Created a connection to the central MySQL database in the Server Explorer
- Failed to create a Local Database Cache with the MySQL connection

The problem is that when I create a new Local Database Cache, the list of available connections does not include my MySQL connection. Furthermore, when I go to create a new connection, there is no MySQL Driver in the list (as opposed to the list available when creating a connection in the Server Explorer).

Any help? I feel that I got this Microsoft Sync Framework all wrong. Or that I am missing something.

I'm looking for tutorials as well. Google wasn't really helpful (neither was Microsoft for that matter).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you might have to create a custom sync provider for MySQL, the ADO.NET provider you installed and the actual Sync provider are two different things.

I had a link to a walkthrough for building an Oracle provider, but I seem to have misplaced it. From what I can remember you need to derive your provider from [ServerSyncProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.serversyncprovider(SQL.105).aspx). You might want to check out the [Sync Framework home page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx) as they are likely to have a few posts and videos that should prove useful.

Hope it helps, I'll update this post if I manage to find that tutorial link.

---

Edit: [This](http://www.syncguru.com/projects/SyncServicesDemoOracle.aspx) is the one I was looking for, but it's a little out of date (I suggest you also look at a few of the other posts under [Projects](http://www.syncguru.com/Projects.aspx)). You might also want to look at [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd937288(SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: Indeed, I just noticed that there is a difference between a Sync Provider and a Database Provider... Thank you for your links.. I'll try them out..